Rigorous Proof for Conditional Expectation in Characteristic Functions
I am interested in dealing with characteristic functions of the product of two independent random variables $X$ and $U$. I found this Question very interesting, but I would like to understand, in a very rigorous way, a small detail in its answer. Defining $Z := XU$, the answer begins with:
$$\varphi_Z(t) = \mathbb{E}\left( \exp(i t X U) \right) = \mathbb{E}\left( \mathbb{E}\left( \exp(i t X U) | U\right) \right) \overset{!}{=} \mathbb{E}\left( \varphi_X\left( t U \right) \right)\label{I}\tag{I}
$$
Something that is intriguing me is the last equality, where it is implicitly assumed that:
$$ \mathbb{E}\left( \exp(i t X U) | U\right) = \varphi_X\left( t U \right)\tag{II}\label{II}$$
I want to show this in a very rigorous way and for this, I will start from the definition. Suppose that $Z=XU$ is defined in a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ and let $\mathcal G = \sigma(U)$ be the sub-sigma algebra generated by $U$. Note that $\mathcal G \subset \mathcal F$. Define $Y := \exp\left(i t Z\right)\equiv \exp\left(i t XU\right)$ for some $t \in \mathbb R$ fixed.
We know by definition that $E(Y | U)$ is the unique random variable (a.s.) that satisfies:

$E(Y | U)$ is $\sigma(U)-$measurable;
$\int_G E(Y | U) dP = \int_G Y dP $, $\forall \, G \in \sigma(U)$.

So, my strategy to show (\ref{II}) is to try to use the a.s. uniqueness and the second condition:
$$\int_G \varphi_X\left( t U \right) dP = \int_{G} \exp\left(i t XU\right) dP, \quad \forall \, G \in \sigma(U).$$
I honestly don't know if there is another more pragmatic and rigorous way to show (\ref{II}).
Any alternative to show (\ref{II}) or guidance from you will be of great value.
Attempt:
Using the hints given in the comments, I found this other Question that seems to be exactly the result that is suggested in comments. We can see its demonstration (using Fubini) in its corresponding answer. Here is an adaptation for my case:

Let $X$ and $U$ be independent random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, P)$ with images $(\Omega_X, \mathcal{A}_X)$, $(\Omega_U,\mathcal{A}_U)$ and $f: \Omega_X \times \Omega_Y\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ integrable. We have:
$$E[f(X,U)|U] = \int f(x,U) P^X(dx)\tag{III}\label{III}$$

Note that by definition:
$$\varphi_X(t U)= E\left[ \exp{(itUX) }\right]= \int \exp{(itUx) } P^X(dx)\tag{IV}\label{IV}$$
So, (\ref{II}) follows trivially and directly using (\ref{III}) and (\ref{IV}) with $f(X,U)= \exp{(i t UX)}$, for $t$ fixed.

$\int_G \varphi_X\left( t U \right) dP = \int_{G} \exp\left(i t XU\right) dP, \quad \forall , G \in \sigma(U)$ is what you need, and you can prove this using Fubini's Theorem.

I find it useful to mention, that this in particular follows from more general theorem. If you have $\sigma-$field $\mathcal G$ and random variables $X,Y$ such that $X$ is $\mathcal G$ measurable and $Y$ is independent of $\mathcal G$, then for any measurable function $f$ such that $\mathbb E|f(X,Y)| < \infty$ we have $\mathbb E[ f(X,Y)|\mathcal G] = H(X)$, where $H(t) = \mathbb E[f(t,Y)]$.

Dear all, thank you very much for your guidance. I edited the question with my attempt. With your hints, I think the result follows trivially (If there is any error or gaffe that I am making, please let me know, I appreciate your warning). For bibliographical reference purposes, could you tell me if this result has a name or is stated in any book? Thanks.

Looks like Fubini's theorem since $X$ and $U$ are independent and so, their joint distribution is of the product type.
